# How to align top tables row?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I have this simple latex table, I want to align top rows(Day, Min Temp, Max Temp) top. How Can I do it ?

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{8cm} |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & 
            \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \begin{itemize}
                \setlength{\itemindent}{-.2in}
                \setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}
            \item El 1
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} 
    \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Thank in advanced !!
[image]

Comment: please, next time provide complete small document beginning wit `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` containing your table. now people who like to help you should guessing about your document preamble ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change

```
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
```

to

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
```

i.e., add the `[t]` positioning specifier.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example), with some additional tweaks to your code to make the tabular material more appealing from a purely aesthetic point of view.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{8cm} |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}
         \begin{itemize}
                \setlength{\itemindent}{-.2in}
                \setlength\itemsep{-0.5em}                
            \item El 1
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2\strut
         \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage} \\ 
    \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ 
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `enumitem` package you can define your own `itemize` environment for tables. In the second example I have used `tabularx` to make the table as wide as the textwidth:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,nosep,after=\strut,align=parleft,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{8cm} |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & 

            \begin{tabitemize}
            \item El 1
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
        \end{tabitemize}

    \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ | l | l | l | X |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & 

            \begin{tabitemize}
            \item El 1
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
        \end{tabitemize}

    \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

For a more open look of the table, you could also use the `booktabs` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{tabitemize}{itemize}{1}
\setlist[tabitemize]{label=\textbullet,nosep,after=\strut,align=parleft,leftmargin=*,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{  l  l  l  X }
    \toprule
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & 

            \begin{tabitemize}
            \item El 1
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
            \item El 2
        \end{tabitemize}

    \\ \midrule
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The baselines of "El 1" and of the other header items don't seem to matched up perfectly in either of the screenshots. Can you think of a way to fix this?

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for pointing this out. I did not notice that. Aparently, changing from `before=\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}` to `before=\vspace{-0.7\baselineskip}` should improve the alignment.

Comment: Another approach would consist of adding `\newenvironment{mylist}{\begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize}\begin{tabitemize}}{\end{tabitemize}\end{minipage}}` in the preamble and using `\begin{mylist}` and `\end{mylist}` in the body of the document. This would obviate the need to specify any kind of `before=...` adjustments.